# Issue with multiple sites on same vps with haproxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

### Setup

I have a `VPS` which I am using `docker` on. I currently have 3 containers. 1 for haproxy and the other 2 containers contain their individual sites (running a nodejs http server on port 8080).

I have the following domain and subdomains.

- mydomain.com
- deus.ex.machina.mydomain.com
- fela.mydomain.com

I would like for `mydomain.com` to go the the first of the two node servers and `fela.mydomain.com` to go to the other node server. The third domain `deus.ex.machina.mydomain.com` should go to an ip address that doesn't exist, to simulate a server going down so I can make sure the 503 page is displayed.

Here is my `haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option http-server-close
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000

listen stats
    bind       :1988
    stats uri /

frontend http-in
        bind *:80

        # define hosts
        acl host_deusexmachina  hdr_beg(host) -i deus.ex.machina.mydomain.com
        acl host_fela           hdr_beg(host) -i fela.mydomain.com
        acl host_mydomain       hdr_beg(host) -i mydomain.com

        # figure out which one to use
        use_backend deusexmachina_cluster   if host_deusexmachina
        use_backend fela_cluster            if host_fela
        use_backend mydomain_cluster        if host_mydomain

backend deusexmachina_cluster

        balance roundrobin
        cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache

        server deusexmachina_s1 172.17.0.99:8080 check cookie deusexmachina_s1

backend fela_cluster

        balance roundrobin
        cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache

        server fela_s1 172.17.0.59:8080 check cookie fela_s1

backend mydomain_cluster

        balance roundrobin
        cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache

        server mydomain_s1 172.17.0.50:8080 check cookie mydomain_s1
```

- 172.17.0.50:8080 is working (nodejs on port 8080)
- 172.17.0.59:8080 is working (nodejs on port 8080)
- 172.17.0.99:8080 is not working (simulate nodejs down)

All the requests to all three are coming from the same ip address(same device), the reason behind why I have `option http-server-close`.

### Problem

That leaves the question: *what is the issue?*

They are redirecting correctly approximately 90% of the time.

- If I connect to `mydomain.com` and hit the refresh button 9 times out of 10 the correct page will show up (172.17.0.50:8080), the 1 odd time will display 503 (as if it was directed to `deus.ex.machina.mydomain.com` or maybe it was the server? I don't know how to check this).
- For `fela.mydomain.com` when hitting the refresh button, 9 times out of 10 the correct page will show up (172.17.0.59:8080), the 1 odd time will display the `mydomain.com` (not 503 page) page (172.17.0.50:8080).
- And the same goes for `deus.ex.machina.mydomain.com` when hitting the refresh button, 9 times out of 10 the correct page will show up (503 error), the 1 odd time will display the `mydomain.com` (not 503 page) page (172.17.0.50:8080).

Adding `option httpclose` makes it even worse 50/50 chance of it redirecting to the wrong page.

I have all 3 domains open in tabs in the same chrome browser, I switch between them and refresh them.

I suspect haproxy is mixing up the requests? Perhaps caching which backend an ip request should go to? As seen I am using cookies which should direct  the request to the correct server (I've checked the client cookies and they are all in order). I've been at this for hours now, don't really know what else to try.

Comment: Please post the haproxy logs

Comment: What is the version of `haproxy`? Debugging steps: 1. Enable HTTP logging. 2. Use `wget` or `curl` to make distinct requests and watch the response headers. 3. Watch the logs of the loadbalancer as well as the appservers.